# Two different openssl versions when installing parallel versions

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ssl, openssl

I want to install a parallel openssl version in a server to enable kernel tls. As I cannot work directly on the server, I created the next Dockerfile to install openssl 3.1.0 with enable-ktls:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM ubuntu:latest 
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential cmake zlib1g-dev libcppunit-dev git subversion wget && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-3.0.1.tar.gz -O - | tar -xz
WORKDIR /openssl-3.0.1
RUN ./config enable-ktls --prefix=/usr/local/openssl --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl && make && make install
```

Then when I run apps/openssl I get those two versions:

```
root@9dba9fef1455:/openssl-3.0.1# apps/openssl version -a
OpenSSL 3.0.1 14 Dec 2021 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)
built on: Thu Oct 27 17:06:56 2022 UTC
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64)
compiler: gcc -fPIC -pthread -m64 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -Wa,--noexecstack -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/openssl-WsPfAX/openssl-3.0.2=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -DOPENSSL_TLS_SECURITY_LEVEL=2 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_BUILDING_OPENSSL -DNDEBUG -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-3"
MODULESDIR: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ossl-modules"
Seeding source: os-specific
CPUINFO: OPENSSL_ia32cap=0x7ffef3ffffebffff:0x40417f5ef3bfb7ef
```

The problem is that whenever I try to execute a server with that library I get the error:

```
apps/openssl s_server -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -tls1_2 -cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 -accept 443 -ktls
s_server: Unknown option: -ktls
```

So I guess that it is using the openssl library from server and not from docker. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The `openssl` command you execute is not the one you installed on `docker`, this is why I guess you have a problem.
Try specifying the path to the `openssl` binary in `docker` directly when running the `s_server`.

Try this `/apps/openssl/apps/openssl s_server -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -tls1_2 -cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 -accept 443 -ktls`

Comment: Thank you so much! I already tried that solution running the binary located in apps (the openssl in the docker) but did not get success so far :(

Comment: You welcome :) Dont forget to accept the answer if you think it fixed your problem